# There is no valid Keystore defined for this app

Tags: google-maps, react-native, expo

I want to add google maps api to my react-native project. I follow the doc but when i run expo fetch:android:hashes give me those errors

There is no valid Keystore defined for this app
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: F:\React-Native-Redux-Nodejs-Firebase\instagram-clone\instagram-clone.tmp.jks
 Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

It means you have no Keystore at your app. Create it one and this isse will resolved. You can create Keystore using this command:

```
expo credentials:manager
```

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't already run expo build:android for this project, you'll need to do that first before getting the Google Certificate Fingerprint

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to export from expo kit if you're using `react-native-maps`.
2. `expo fetch:android:hashes` This will work only if you've made an build or release .apk file using expo. This command will fetch for the keystore which is automatically saved in your expo project while creating a build.

Answer (score 3):

You should provide SHA256 first

Comment: How is the way to do it? Would you explain a little more? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For windows: Make sure you install Java and set path for JDK/bin folder in C Drive. Run the commands in new terminal

```sh
expo fetch:android:hashes
```

Answer (score 0):

Also note that "expo fetch:android:hashes" is currently deprecated. The new command for eas users to get keystore passwords is "npx eas credentials".