# get the fingerprint of my Expo application

Tags: react-native, google-maps, expo

I want to create an application with `Expo` and use `react-native-maps.` 
But to use the `google map api` I have to provide a digital fingerprint thanks to this command :

> expo fetch:android:hashes

but keytool is not installed and I don't know how to install it on my Ubuntu.

This problem seems to be similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57947980/there-is-no-valid-keystore-defined-for-this-app) 
but I also don't know how to made an build or release .apk file using expo.

thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to install JDK first and then use the toolkit.